# Using command line to save large amount of HTML files

Tags: shell, command-line

I Have website I need to save a large amount of pages from.  The pages are in incremental order, index.php?id=1, index.php?id=2....  Is there a shell script(using mac) I could run to loop through all of these pages and save them individually into a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
url='http://example.com/index.php?='
dir='path/to/dir'
filename=file
extension=ext

for i in {1..100}
do
    wget "$url$i" -O "$dir$filename$i.$ext"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
for i in {1..100}; do wget http://www.example.com/index.php?id=${i}; done
```